# How to iterate through *T funcs from struct over reflect.TypeOf(interface{})?

Tags: go, struct, interface, reflect

I'm having a few problems iterating through `*T funcs` from a `struct` using `reflect`.

I've searched a lot of answers but none seems to talk specifically about this situation.

I've found a `reflect.NewAt` at golang documentation but to be honest I didn't understand, and again I couldn't find a single answer for my situation.

For a better understanding... by having the following struct:

```golang
type Counter struct {}
func (self *Counter) Add(n int) {}
```

If I use reflect by calling the struct pointer itself, it works as expected:

```golang
y := reflect.TypeOf(&Counter{})

for k := 0; k < y.NumMethod(); k++ {
    fmt.Println(y.Method(k)) // {Add  func(*Counter, int) <func(*Counter, int) Value> 0}
}
```

But in my case, multiple structs can arrive here, so it arrives as an interface:

```golang
var p interface{} = Counter{}

z := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(p))

for k := 0; k < z.NumMethod(); k++ {
   fmt.Println(z.Method(k)) // 0x47d150
}
```

But as shown, it prints the memory address.

I expect the `0x47d150` to be the same output as I was using the pointer directly. What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value `y` a `reflect.Type`. The `Method` method on a type is the equivalent of a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions).

The value `z` is a `reflect.Value`. The `Method` method on a value is the equivalent of a [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values).

The printed representation is different because method expressions and method values are not the same thing.

Use `reflect.PtrTo` to get pointer type for a type:

```
var p interface{} = Counter{}
z := reflect.PtrTo(reflect.TypeOf(p))
for k := 0; k < z.NumMethod(); k++ {
    fmt.Println(z.Method(k))  // {Add  func(*Counter, int) <func(*Counter, int) Value> 0}
}
```

The concrete value in the interface is a non-pointer value. You can use this code if the concrete value in the interface is the pointer type:

```
var p interface{} = &Counter{}
z := reflect.TypeOf(p)
for k := 0; k < z.NumMethod(); k++ {
    fmt.Println(z.Method(k)) // {Add  func(*Counter, int) <func(*Counter, int) Value> 0}
}
```

Comment: I'd ask the question of why we're at this level in abstraction in the first place. Unless we're trying to grab stack information?

Comment: I'm asking why one would want to reflect on methods of a type with a known function signature. I feel it's fairly rare to not have your needs met by a proper interface in that instance.

Comment: @LeeJacobs I'm developing a tool that converts Structs to Javascript object. A file containing a []interface{} filled with structs will be iterated and generate the Javascript objects.

Comment: @CeriseLimón How the hell I didn't noticed this function anywhere? LOL

Thanks brother!

Comment: @alexandremoraes why? https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/ creating json objects from structs exists. Unless you're creating something more along the lines of transcoding?

Comment: @LeeJacobs I'm creating a fully transpiled object (including funcs) from a go struct. json.Marshal does not work in this case.